# Using Apache Cordova Plugins for Tizen Project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, tizen

I need to port an existing Apache Cordova project to Tizen platform. Though Tizen Studio does support web application development, how can the plugins used in Apache Cordova be used in the Tizen Project?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a couple of links at:

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Cordova

Will it help ?

Comment: I've been able to run the project by just copying the js/www/css folders from the Cordova project. However, the issue is with the plugins used by cordova such as navigation whose equivalent I'm unable to find for Tizen.